# Which capitalization style to use for article titles in CV?

Tags: publications, writing, cv

This likely varies by field; I am in the social sciences, but general insights on the topic are welcome.

We have two common capitalization schemes for article titles:

- Title case (e.g. "Longitudinal Study of Cookie Consumption During Christmas")
- Sentence case (e.g. "Longitudinal study of cookie consumption during Christmas")

Right now I list the title for each article as it appears in the journal. However, this means that the alternating papers are listed using different capitalization schemes, which doesn't look good and decreases readability (especially if someone is scanning the CV quickly). Admittedly, this doesn't have a huge effect, but I would still prefer to stick with a single style, especially as it wouldn't take me a lot of time to dp this, and the CV plays a large role in my career.

I searched, but couldn't find recommendations regarding this, and there is no single style which is prevalent in CVs in my field (which also emphasizes the fact that it's probably not too crucial).

**My question** is which capitalization style would be preferable in terms of appearance and readability: title case or sentence case?

Thank you.

Comment: Listing each title as it appears in the journal seems a bad choice, since some journals print the titles of papers in all capital letters.  In my opinion, either of the styles you list would be fine if used consistently.

Comment: You're overthinking it: just pick one and be consistent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stylistic choices are not within the purview of academia.se.

Comment: @RoboKaren: I understand, but that's why I emphasized the focus on CV readability. I was hoping someone could give a definitive answer (if there is one) regarding which style makes it easier to read a CV, especially as such documents are frequently "scanned" by readers in a short amount of time. Of course, if more people agree with the comments so far, then it probably doesn't matter which style is used, as long as it is used consistently (which is also a helpful answer).

Comment: This is entirely up to you. I would myself adopt a consistent style. No one is going to notice you're you're using the 'wrong' capitalization for a particular journal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sentence casing would be my personal choice, but actually it is just a matter of preference.

Academic CVs exist in either title casing or sentence casing in publications. Both are prevalent in practice. Whatever be your choice, make sure it is consistent throughout the CV.